# How Do I Mark A RequestParam As Optional In Swagger?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I am generating the swagger docs for my REST API using SpringFox.

I have added an optional parameter to my API now:

```
@ApiOperation(
  value = "Get all cars"
)
@GetMapping(value = "/cars", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<CarDTO>> getCars(
  @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer page,
  @RequestParam(required = false) String status) {
  ResponseDTO<CarDTO> response = service.getCars(page, status);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

How do I highlight in the swagger docs that one is required and the other is optional?

Answer (score 1):

You have the [`@ApiParam`](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html) annotation you can use, it has a property `required` which you can put to `true` or `false` depending on your needs

```
@ApiOperation(
  value = "Get all cars"
)
@GetMapping(value = "/cars", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<CarDTO>> getCars(
  @ApiParam(required = true) @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer page,
  @ApiParam(required = false) @RequestParam(required = false) String status) {
  ResponseDTO<CarDTO> response = service.getCars(page, status);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html), it has other properties like

- `access`
- `allowableValues`
- `allowMultiple`
- `defaultValue`
- `name`
- `value`

Answer (score 1):

You have the **@ApiParam** annotation you can use, it has a property **hidden** which you can put to **true** or **false**.

Ex.:

@ApiParam(value = ".....", defaultValue = "true", hidden = true) @QueryParam("restricao") boolean restricao